# Updating/Deleting a row in listview that includes a countdown timer

Tags: c#, listview, timer

Currently i am having trouble updating a row in my listview that contains both text and a timer that counts down. So far I've tried updating the entire row as well as trying to update just the text and i get an error in each instance.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index

I am also having a slight problem with the delete button. It deletes the row as planned but it appears the information is still running in the background and haven't come across any info on how to delete the session. I pray for your guidance.

```
 private void Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CSession newSession = new CSession();

        if(PasswordText.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password not entered");
            return;
        }

        newSession.password = PasswordText.Text;
        newSession.purchased_time = workingTimeSpan;
        newSession.remaining_time = workingTimeSpan;
        newSession.status = "Online";

        sessionlist.Add(newSession);
        PasswordText.Text = "";
        TimerLabel.Text = "";
        workingTimeSpan = new TimeSpan();
    }

    private void DisplayAllSessions()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        foreach(CSession c in sessionlist)
        {
            string[] row = { c.password, c.purchased_time.ToString(), c.remaining_time.ToString(), c.status };
            ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem(row);
            listView1.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(CSession c in sessionlist)
        {
            
            if (c.remaining_time.TotalMinutes == 5 && !c.MessageDisplayed)
            {
                c.MessageDisplayed = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Time almost up for client.");
                
            }

            if (c.remaining_time.TotalSeconds < 1)
            {
                c.status = "Offline";
            }
           
            if(c.status == "Online")
            {
               c.remaining_time -= oneSecond;
            }

        }

        DisplayAllSessions();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }
 
    private void updatebutton()
    {
        listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = PasswordText.Text;

        PasswordText.Text = "";
    }

     private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updatebutton();
    }
    
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordText.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        TimerLabel.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
    }

    private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to delete.", "Removing User", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"...i get an error..."_ - what error?

Comment: Sorry still not used to how much info im supposed to leave.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: Ive tried looking up various ways of just getting the text to change hoping it would lead me in the right direction but i think all the methods i found dont take the timer into consideration and so far i havnt found anything on updating a timer in listview

Comment: Managed to get it somehow through banging my head and a ton of reading but i can now remove and update a row even if the code isnt very neat

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer below where you can gain possible upvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used for the update function and delete row function.

```
 private void updatebutton()
    {
        CSession updatedsession = new CSession();
        int updateindex = 0;
        int index = 0;
        foreach (CSession lookup in sessionlist)
        {
            if(lookup.password == PasswordText.Text)
            {

                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to add time.", "Adding Time", 
          MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    updatedsession = lookup;
                    updateindex = index;
                    
                }
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        updatedsession.purchased_time = workingTimeSpan + 
        updatedsession.purchased_time;
        updatedsession.remaining_time = workingTimeSpan + 
        updatedsession.remaining_time;

        sessionlist[updateindex] = updatedsession;
        //sortedSessionList[PasswordText.Text] = updatedsession;
        PasswordText.Text = "";
        TimerLabel.Text = "";
        workingTimeSpan = new TimeSpan();
    }

     private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            updatebutton();
    }

 private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CSession cSession = new CSession();

            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to delete.", "Removing User", 
          MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (CSession c in sessionlist)
                {
                    
                    if(c.password == PasswordText.Text)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
                    
                }
                sessionlist.RemoveAt(index);
            }
        
    }
```